# Where is latest python 3.3 bindary build for windows platform?

Tags: python, windows, windows-installer, python-3.3

You maybe ask why do I use python 3.3 any way. 
Because, I am running postgresql on windows. The plpython module shipped with pgsql 9.6 is linked to python33.dll

According to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0398/#id7
There is only source release.
Why do python only release source tar ball ? Wouldn't it make windows platform less secure ?
Is there any other trusted source where people can get the latest 3.3.7 x86 binary installer ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Python downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/) has installers for any version you care to name, usually including Windows binary installers. PEPs aren't the place to look for them.

It looks like 3.3.6 was only done as a source release (it's possible they'd moved support on to 3.4 and later by that point), so 3.3.5 is the last one with precompiled official binaries. Not sure what happened to 3.3.7; the PEP may be incorrect and the 3.3.7 release was scrubbed.

Comment: Yeah, looks you are right, 3.3.7 seems to be nowhere. I'd leave this open for a few days, see if any trusted pre-compiled source available for 3.3.6. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, still can't find any. Unless I compile by myself.

Answer (score 1):

The last binary release was 3.3.5.

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-335/

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the missing 3.3.6 or 3.3.7 which have security fixes.

Comment: Python 3.3.6 and 3.3.7 are source-only releases which you'll need to build yourself. Python 3.3 is expected to EOL on 2017-09-29. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0398/#x-end-of-life